# CSS overriding Semantic React Ui Properties

Tags: css, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I want to override default Header that belong to react semantic UI.

Currently I positioned my Header inside div in order to style it.

```
    <div className="portfolioTitle">
      <Header as="h1">Check the magic</Header>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
   .portfolioTitle {
      padding-left: 10%;
      position: relative;
      padding-bottom: 3%;
      padding-top: 3%;
    }
```

This solution is working, but I want to do the same without using div. 
I tried to implement [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47213044/css-overriding-ui-properties-with-or-without-important), but it's not working for me.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply give the [className prop](https://react.semantic-ui.com/elements/header/#types-page) to the `Header`

[See working demo here](https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-example-css-classname-u1pbb?file=/example.js)

Also you need to apply `!important` to the styles.

**Note**: If you inspect element, you will see that the below styles are applied to `Header` by semantic ui library. So if you want to provide custom className then with below mentioned css properties then you have to use `!important`.

```js
.ui.header {
    border: none;
    margin: calc(2rem - .14285714em) 0 1rem;
    padding: 0 0;
    font-family: Lato,'Helvetica Neue',Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1.28571429em;
    text-transform: none;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.87);
}
```

Comment: Tried it. But it doesn't working.
Am I doing it wrong?

  <Header className="portfolioTitle" as="h1">
          Check the magic
   </Header>

Also implemented !important. Doesn't help either.

Comment: add !important to your styles..see the code in the demo link

Comment: i've updated the answer with more explanation ... hope it is clear.

Comment: Yes.  It is some weird bug in my code. When I copy the code into the sandbox everything is working.
Thank you. I will find what's wrong with it.